# Can't callgrind support AVX2 instructions?

Tags: c++11, valgrind, avx2

I'm trying to profile my program written with Intel AVX2 instructions using valgrind. The program run smoothly under memcheck. But when I run with callgrind (`valgrind --tool=callgrind`), it terminates with unrecognized instruction error. I check the [release note](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html) of Valgrind 3.9.0 and it says `Support for Intel AVX2 instructions.  This is available only on 64 bit code.`. I compile my program with `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -mavx2 -m64` but the error remains. Part of the output is as below:

```
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x16 0xC5 0xDD 0x64 0xD2 0xC5 0xF5 0xDB
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=NONE
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
 ==6775== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x43d1c9.
==6775==    at 0x43D1C9: byteslice::ByteSliceColumnBlock<16ul, (byteslice::Direction)1>::Scan(bytes
lice::Comparator, unsigned long, byteslice::BitVectorBlock*, byteslice::Bitwise) const (avxintrin.h
:965)
==6775==    by 0x45DEAD: byteslice::Column::Scan(byteslice::Comparator, unsigned long, byteslice::B
itVector*, byteslice::Bitwise) const (column.cpp:113)
==6775==    by 0x4017C9: main (simple.cpp:89)
```

**Edit**: I find the error depends on optimization level. There's no error with -O0. But error shows up with -O1 and above.

Comment: are you using valgrind 3.9.0, or later?

Comment: @BЈовић I am using Valgrind 3.9.0.